# AysncTask doInBackground() with ToggleButton and EditText

Tags: java, android

I've managed to make it run to the point after the dialog is pressed, it runs the main UI, but eventually it crashed after I moved to another EditText. I'm not how do I use the onProgressUpdate() to make sure that my EditText are disabled accordingly.

What I'm looking for is, if the user clicks Large Character, I want the program to check the ToggleButton condition with a While loop. If its still ON, I want it to basically check for the EditText focus and have some SetOnFocusChangeListener(); It gave me an error saying the `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

This is my main class in onCreate():

```
         //Row 1-4 EditText
         row1TextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.row1);
         row2TextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.row2);
         row3TextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.row3);
         row4TextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.row4);

        //ToggleButton
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle1);


        AlertDialog.Builder characterChoose = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        characterChoose.setTitle("Character Input Option");
        characterChoose.setMessage("Please choose the option the below").setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Large Character", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                toggleButton.setTextOn("LARGE");
                toggleButton.setChecked(true);
                backgroundThread bckgnd = new backgroundThread();
                bckgnd.execute();





            }
```

This is my AsyncTask class:

```
private class backgroundThread extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>{

        //Run on background thread.
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
            while(toggleButton.isChecked())
            {
                if(row1TextField.isFocused())
                {
                    row2TextField.setEnabled(false);
                }

                row2TextField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View textfield3, boolean isFocus) {
                        if(textfield3.isFocused())
                        {
                            row3TextField.setEnabled(false);
                        }

                    }

                });

                row3TextField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View textfield3, boolean isFocus) {
                        if(textfield3.isFocused())
                        {
                            row4TextField.setEnabled(false);
                        }

                    }

                });

        }
            return null;

    }
```

Logcat

```
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4888)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:975)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4125)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10521)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateDrawable(TextView.java:4849)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.invalidateDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:250)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:382)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setVisible(Drawable.java:578)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:307)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:106)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:494)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:14372)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.widget.TextView.drawableStateChanged(TextView.java:3381)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:14386)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:5733)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.widget.TextView.setEnabled(TextView.java:1402)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at com.example.dotmatrixledpanel.startPage2$backgroundThread.doInBackground(startPage2.java:313)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at com.example.dotmatrixledpanel.startPage2$backgroundThread.doInBackground(startPage2.java:1)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-03 07:54:17.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4871):     ... 5 more
```

So I would like to know, what should I put in the onProgressUpdate method or should I use a Runnable?

Comment: Why you do that in an AsyncTask ? Because that's the problem here.

Comment: I did not exactly understand what you are trying to achieve but the error you get reminds me that if you need to change a view from another thread you definitely need to use a Handler
Check here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: Sorry for that guys. I've just started learning AsyncTask and I thought that is how it works but turns out no. I'm just trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do changes on the UI in the doInBackground() method of an async task. For that you have to use the method onPostExecute() of the async task. So your doInBackground() should return a boolean or something you want, so you can change the UI in the onPostExecute() method.

Comment: So since, I don't have any calculation, the doInBackground is useless for my case? Or just leave the `while(toggleButton.isChecked()) there?

Comment: Since doInBackground can't touch your view elements yes. For your case you will need a handler: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: So if I were to use a Handler, AsyncTask is not needed right? I'll need to use a Thread?

Comment: To be honest im not entirely sure what you trying to achieve in the end. From what i understand i dont see a reason to use any task at all? Why do you have to make a loop?

Comment: I was following a tutorial on it, so I was wondering if an AsyncTask would work. But I think a myThread implements Runnable would be easier to work with. 

I need to change the editText.isFocused depending on the users FocusChange and the ToggleButton status.

Comment: Yea but thats exactly what the View.OnFocusChangeListener and the onToggleClicked methods are for. Everytime you change focus or click the toggle you can just check the status, no need to check it it all the time, since as long as no changes happen you don't want to change anything?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Comment: But my program requires a while loop for my ToggleButton, without a thread, I don't think the UI will keep running right?

Comment: Without a thread your UI wont keep running that is correct. But why do you need a while loop? Do you have to perform the same action over and over again while its toggled? If you just have to wait till the toogle gets pressed again you can use onToggleClicked.

Comment: I'll have a look at onToggleClicked. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll tick your answer if it helped. Sorry for the inconvenience. Because apparently, I tried using onToggleClicked. But the Focus didn't change back to my first EditText when the button is toggle. Is there a specific command to use, if a button is toggle, move the cursor or the focus to my first edittext

Comment: Nevermind, it worked :) Thanks a lot though. I'm sorry to cause you some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

No UI touches from `doInBackground()` is allowed. Check AsyncTask docs first: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a
>   background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread.

If you need to update anything on UI side you need to do that in either `onPreExecute()` or `onPostExecute()`.

**EDIT**

I am failing to see any reason to use `AsyncTask` in your code at all.

Comment: I've tried using without AsyncTask or a Thread. My app simply hangs there when there is a while loop. So my thought was to either implement an AsyncTask or a class that extends Runnable